# HTML/CSS reverse direction progress bar

Tags: html, css

How do you program a reversed direction progress bar that aligns to the right and has text?

[image]

[Here's my css](http://codepen.io/qdarkness/pen/KADLi) thus far but it keeps displaying as if it is starting from the left. Originally I was coding it to transition(ease-out) but I could not find a way to have it start from the right and extend to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `ul.skillbars li`, add `text-align:right;`.

On `ul.skillbars li:after` and `ul.skillbars-r li:after`, change `left` to `right`.

Update your gradients as needed.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hfcwB

**Edit**

I misread the question; thought you wanted all of the bars aligned right, my mistake!

To have them side by side, I'd recommend adding the following instead of using `float`(there's arguments for both, I just like not having to worry about `clear`ing):

```
ul{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Then on the two `ul`s add:

```
width: 50%;
margin-left:-4px;
```

On `ul.skillbars-r li:after`, still change `left` to `right`.

There we go! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BhvJI

Comment: @user2588644 This code doesn't produce anything like your image, at least on Firefox 25. But maybe I didn't understand well your problem, because I don't find your question very clear.

Comment: @Oriol, sorry! I actually flipped it back because how it had it in the example was right aligning both of them but it showed me how to do it. I tried your way as well but for some reason the floats were squishing my bars (I'm using foundation as my base, so maybe thats why?). However I did use your example to help me clean up my code from the extra variables that I was repeating, so thank you as well!

Comment: @Oriol I had the same question - it wasn't entirely clear if OP wanted all to the right or one both directions. Yours is a clean solution, I like it!. I've also updated mine to show both ways.

Comment: @DACrosby I ultimately used yours because you still kept "left: and right:" which seemed to work better than applying floats in my case. Is there a reason to use one over the other? I think the reason might have had to do with the fact that I have them separately in two different foundation columns and they fill it completely. I'm not sure if that's best practice, but that is how I ended up doing it.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/fQtnb/1/

Use

HTML:

```
<ul class="skillbars l">
  <li class="eight"><span>P</span></li> 
  <li class="ten"><span>I</span></li> 
  <li class="nine"><span>I</span></li> 
  <li class="eight"><span>F</span></li> 
  <li class="nine"><span>D</span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="skillbars r">
  <li class="six"><span>A</span></li> 
  <li class="nine"><span>H</span></li> 
  <li class="six"><span>W</span></li> 
  <li class="seven"><span>M</span></li> 
  <li class="eight"><span>3</span></li> 
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}

#skills {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 300;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

ul.skillbars {
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}

ul.skillbars li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.188em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.skillbars.r li {
  text-align: right;
}


ul.skillbars li span {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 300;
  font-size: 1em;
}

ul.skillbars li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #104000; /* Old browsers */
}

ul.skillbars.l li:after {
left: 3px;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #000000 0%, #104000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#104000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #000000 0%,#104000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #000000 0%,#104000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #000000 0%,#104000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,  #000000 0%,#104000 100%); /* W3C */

}

ul.skillbars.r li:after {
right: 3px;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #104000 0%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#104000), color-stop(100%,#000000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #104000 0%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #104000 0%,#000000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #104000 0%,#000000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,  #104000 0%,#000000 100%); /* W3C */
}

ul.skillbars li.six:after {
  width: 60%;
}

ul.skillbars li.seven:after {
  width: 70%;
}

ul.skillbars li.eight:after {
  width: 80%;
}

ul.skillbars li.nine:after {
  width: 90%;
}

ul.skillbars li.ten:after {
  width: 95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: right;` on the progress bar so that it starts on the right

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I tried that and it came up with some undesirable effect. Essentially pushing the progress bar to the right and having the left still be the start of it.

Comment: I have not, is it compatible across most browsers? And will it end up flipping the text that I want to have displayed in there as well? As well, should I be placing the transform on the <li> itself or the entire <ul>?

Comment: Yes actually it would flip the text but you could have is separately and then push it on with position absolute